# CSS: Can I refer a value of a attribute in a attribute selector

Tags: html, css

Better explain my problem using examples:

I have a html file that contains something like

```
<a name="2846" href="Data.Product.html#2846" class="Function"> ... </a>
<a name="2877" href="Data.Product.html#2846" class="Function"> ... </a>
<a name="2911" href="Data.Product.html#2911" class="Function"> ... </a>
```

I want to select (by means of CSS selectors) elements  that have class "Function", with href attribute ends with the exact value of name attribute. In the example above, only the following two will be selected

```
<a name="2846" href="Data.Product.html#2846" class="Function"> ... </a>
<a name="2911" href="Data.Product.html#2911" class="Function"> ... </a>
```

I think about that, maybe something along the line `a.Function[href$=?]`. My question is can I refer to the value of name attribute in a selector, is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: two loops are necessary here.

Comment: it's requrie javascript are you okay ??

Comment: I was looking for a solution using only CSS selectors.

Comment: @JeremyBi It's not possible in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Two loops are necessary in your case. One to fetch all `Function` class elements and then check whether the `href` attribute has the `name` attribute value in it.

Try this:

```js
var filteredEls = Array.prototype.filter.call( // Convert NodeList to Array
  document.getElementsByClassName('Function'), // Get all "Function" class elements
  function(el) {
    return el.getAttribute('href') === "Data.Product.html#" + el.name; // Filter elements with the condition
  }
);

console.dir(filteredEls); // check console
```

```html
<a name="2846" href="Data.Product.html#2846" class="Function"> ... </a>
<a name="2877" href="Data.Product.html#2846" class="Function"> ... </a>
<a name="2911" href="Data.Product.html#2911" class="Function"> ... </a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if it is possible to use only CSS selectors.

Comment: @JeremyBi I highly doubt that. Sorry I overlooked absence of JavaScript tag. I will keep this post if you are ok with it.